# Einbilden vs. Imagine

Tags: english, etymology, german

One of the German words for Imagine is Einbilden, which I believe literally translates to "in-picture".

This made me think of the fact that Imagine itself has the prefix Im-, which (together with In-) is often correlated with the German Ein- (Impression = Eindruck, Import = Einführen, Intimidate = Einschüchtern, etc.).

The [current etymology by wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=imago&oldid=59821207#Etymology_6) doesn't break Imagine like this. Though I was thinking perhaps Imagine could be broken down to Im + latin ăgo ?

Comment: _imago_ is related to the stem of _imitari_, and _mimeomai_ ("copy") in Greek. No realtion to _ago_.

Answer (score 2):

No. The Latin prefix is *in-* and before a vowel, it remains unchanged, giving **in-ago* > *inigo*. But this is a verb, and not a noun, and there is no way to derive the noun *imago* from that verb.

*in-* becomes *im-* by assimilation in front of the consonants *b*, *p*, and *m* in Latin, but nowhere else.